# What does a quantifier with a subscript mean?

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers

Is there a difference between $\forall x$ and $\forall_{x}$?

I saw someone write $\forall_{x} \text{ Qt}(x)$, and I want to know whether that is the same as $\forall x \text{ Qt}(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a different notational convention.

It comes from following the format of a conjunctive series, $\bigwedge_x Q(x)$, which was once used as notation for universal quantification. $~\forall x~Q(x)$ is the most current convention, although the transition form, $\forall_x Q(x)$, is still being used in some texts to date.

Comment: Thanks for explaining where the two variants came from in addition to answering the question.